# Polish Airports' fingerprint Process

Tags: visas, schengen, airport-security, poland

Are there fingerprints taking processes at Polish airports for Schengen visa holders upon arrival and entry in the country?

Earlier, I got a visa from the French Embassy and my fingerprints had been taken in the embassy but not upon entering France. Now I am travelling to Poland and the Embassy didn't take fingerprints for the Schengen visa so I am wondering whether they would be taking them at the airport.

Comment: Do you mean will your fingerprints be compared to those “you” had to give when applying for the visa?

Comment: No , I meant when stamping entry ,are they taking your fingerprints ?

Comment: In some countries they have these devices taking your fingerprints and some scan eyes .

Comment: In the Schengen area? On entry?

Comment: Ya , I want to know about poland's Warsow and Karkow airports

Comment: I might simply be unaware of it but I haver never heard of any country recording fingerprints upon entry or any regulation to mandate or allow this in the Schengen area. What they can definitely do is compare the fingerprints of the person presenting herself to the border to those recorded in the VIS database for her visa and maybe also to fingerprints in the EURODAC and SIS databases. Anyway, why does it matter to you? A bit background might help get a better answer.

Comment: I got a visa from French Embassy and my fingerprints has been taken in the embassy " biometric fingerprint " , and upon entering france there wasn't this process , now I am travelling to Poland in the Embassy they didnt take fingerprints for schengen visa so I wondered they would be taking it in the airport.

Comment: In Japan, all adults must have a picture taken and both of their index fingers scanned, so I assume this is to compare against a watchlist of people not allowed to enter.

Comment: I applied for a polish national visa and my fingerprint was not taken, but I had my fingerprint taken for a shengen visa previously. Is there any problem with this?

Answer (score 4):

Fingerprints are stored in the Visa Information System (VIS) database for five years and can be reused for new visa applications. So the Polish consulate already has your fingerprints on file from the time you applied for a French visa and did not need to collect them again for your new visa.

Beyond that, some consulates are not equipped to collect biometrics (yet) as this is relatively new and still being rolled out, region by region (well, it started in 2011 but these things take time). In principle, all Schengen consulates should eventually do it everywhere, by the end of 2015.

Whatever the case may be, I am not aware of any systematic fingerprinting at airports when the fingerprints are not already on file. It would take a long time and serve little purpose, at least as far as visas are concerned because the main point of the biometrics is to make sure the person presenting herself at the border is indeed the same person who applied for the visa. But if you didn't collect any data during the application for comparison, that's moot.

Of course, border guards at the airport can always take fingerprints on a case-by-case basis to compare them with those in the VIS or possibly other databases like the SIS and EURODAC. In principle, a (mis)match should not automatically result in a removal but it would certainly lead to more extensive questioning.

Comment: I agree to what you mentioned but there were other applicants acquiring schengen visa for the first time and no fingerprints has been taken. How can describe that ?

Comment: @user34814 I almost mentioned it in my answer: Biometrics are still being rolled out, not all Schengen consulates are currently doing it but they should do it soon (1-2 years I think?). But one way or the other, the goal is to take the fingerprints during the application, it does not make sense to collect them at the airport because the whole point is to make sure that the person showing up at the border is still the same person who applied for the visa. But if you don't have anything to compare them to…

Comment: @user34814 Where are you located incidentally? In principle, biometrics are already mandatory in some regions like the Middle East but not in others like East and South Asia. In the places where it's not mandatory, consulates might already be doing it on a voluntary basis.

Comment: Your information is correct , totally agree